# CCheckBoxColumn with cgridview creating checkboxes when moving between pages

Tags: php, yii

I wanted to delete selected columns so I did like this in cgridview and in controller I was able to get the values and delete so every thing is working fine regarding this.

```
array(
    'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
    'id'=>'images-grid',
)
```

But, when I click on pagination numbers check boxes are getting created automatically at bottom.

[image]

and also this top check box which is used to select all is getting disappeared when navigating I think that check box is getting displayed in bottom I guess.

[image]

Please, let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: Problem Solved :)

I was using id of checkbox same as id of cgridview, now I changed it to autoId.

that solved the problem but no Idea why It was creating checkbox below gridview when we navigate and how autoId solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved :) I was using id of checkbox same as id of cgridview, now I changed it to autoId. that solved the problem but no Idea why It was creating checkbox below gridview when we navigate and how autoId solved it. –